# Changing math fonts for Greek letters

Tags: fonts, mathpazo, eulervm

My QUESTION amounts to: is it possible to use `mathpazo` for everything, except for Greek math fonts in `euler`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Letters} {U}{zeur}{m}{n}% Euler
\DeclareMathSymbol\Gamma    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Delta    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Theta    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Lambda   {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Xi       {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Pi       {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Sigma    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Upsilon  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Phi      {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Psi      {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol\Omega    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}   {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}   {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}   {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda} {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}     {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}     {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}     {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}     {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}    {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}  {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi} {\mathalpha}{Letters}{"27}
\DeclareMathSymbol\upOmega  {\mathord}{Letters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol\upDelta  {\mathord}{Letters}{"01}

\begin{document}

Palatino $\Omega$

\end{document}
```

Comment: hmm, eulervm changes all the math fonts, I wanted to use mathpazo's ones for everything except greek letters

Comment: as on page 2 of math.northwestern.edu/~costello/bcov.pdf

Comment: see myedited answer

Comment: thanks, the fonts now match; is there a way to do it without manually change every letter, e.g. a command to specify the Greek math font separately?

Comment: define your own package for that.

Comment: @Herbert What would be the fontname and encoding if I wanted to select greek from MyriadPro package? I tried `{T1}{MyriadPro-LF}..` but it results in different non greek... Or better: Can you update your answer showing how to find out the exact name?

Comment: Got it, it's in `{OML}{MyriadPro-LF}{m}{n}` italics: `0`-`39` and normal: `128`-`169`.